# Why was this edit rejected?

Tags: support

I had an [edit](https://german.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/254) rejected by Community.

What was wrong with this edit?  I felt it clarified the question.

And what does it mean if Community rejects an edit?

---

Update:  see this [meta.SO question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124141/is-there-a-way-to-suggest-a-decision-by-the-community-bot-may-be-wrong/124144#124144) for a similar example.  Apparently, this can happen when two users are editing at the same time.  (Not sure if that's the actual reason why, though -- the timestamps are about 6 minutes apart).

Comment: I didn't reject your edit, nor improved it. When I edited it there were no pending edits there.

Comment: @Gigili -- right: Community rejected it.  Which is the most confusing thing of all.  Looks like this has actually been causing quite a bit of frustration around the SE network.

Comment: I agree with musiKk's comment: Most of the changes aren't substantial. And while on it, you should correct everything `... good? (Präteritum?) . Is ...` should be `... good (Präteritum?)? Is...`. Edits bring old questions to top, so minor edit might be okay in the first days, as long as we stay at 3 questions per day, but I don't see a real error in the question. Well - I'm not a native English speaker. Maybe you can discuss the details on EU&L. ;)

Comment: @MattFenwick: `Editing a post also bumps the question to the top of the homepage. Too many edits can also force a post into community wiki mode. Make your edits count.` [Privileges](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit) Other [front-page-flooding](http://meta.superuser.com/q/3103/35856) links [flooding again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116810/156431). You may search more cases at general meta yourself.

Comment: @userunknown At any rate we're off-topic from what our initial argument was: whether my suggested edit was substantial enough.  I'm sure we could both find people who agreed with us, but I doubt we'll find common ground so I think we'll just have to agree to disagree.  I'm sorry that we couldn't find a consensus.

Comment: I didn't say that you're a prolific editor. But I don't see what's wrong with `to put it in context`. As far as my knowledge of the English language reaches, this is a valid term. `I wanted to ask` doesn't sound like best Oxford English to me, but nothing wrong and worth editing. The same for `Is that equivalent to`. So if I substract these, what is left? I don't see a substantial improvement.

Comment: @userunknown please either stop or let's continue this in chat.  I've flagged your last comment.

Comment: Yes, and I waited 8h in Chat for you. Now, it's too late.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to quote [the answer I got in MSE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3712/who-has-got-more-reps-is-first-in-the-priority-list):

> You suggested an edit which put your edit in the queue.
>
> A different user came in, and made an edit while your suggestion was still in the queue. He was very likely unaware of your edit suggestion.
>
> Since the question was edited, the Community user rejected your pending suggestion, as it pertains to an older version.
>
> So there is no malice. It is just the way the system works.
>
> Another possibility is that the user clicked "Improve" and unchecked the suggested edit is helpful checkbox.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you have the page open for a while before you made your edit? Normally when there's a suggested edit in the queue, all future viewers with edit privileges will see a link that will take them to that suggested edit. I wonder if there's a timing issue here.

Comment: @AnnaLear: I usually just open GL&U to check if there's something new and close it. If there was a suggested edit, I wouldn't edit it.

Answer (score 3):

Hm, I didn't reject it. If I had seen it, I would have accepted it because it would clearly improve the question.

From "[How do suggested edits work? (Meta Stack Overflow)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)"

> Who can vote on a suggested edit?
>
> - The owner of a post may vote to accept or reject any modification of her post.
> - All users with the edit privilege may vote on suggested edits to posts.
> - Users with 5000 rep may vote on suggested edits to tag wikis.

I'm going to apply your edit suggestions right now.

Comment: I believe this is not a debate on **who** or **why** an edit was rejected but how the [Community](http://german.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity) user can do that before we may not even had a chance to approve an edit. I am wondering this too.

Answer (score 1):

The Community user isn't quite that self-aware (*yet...*). When you see a suggested edit rejected (or approved) by Community, it means that someone used one of the "Improve" buttons.

Looks like Gigili disagreed with your suggestion and went the "reject and improve" route to make [their own changes](https://german.stackexchange.com/revisions/4044/2).

Comment: Why does that show up as "Community"?  Very confusing.

Comment: No, I didn't reject Matt's edit. I had the same problem on other SE sites and your answer is not the case.